# How can I remove the remaining \u200d aflter removing emoji with the RegExp in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

1 Using the RegExp replace the emoji

```
"help me ‍✈️‍‍‍‍".replace(/\u{1F3F4}(?:\u{E0067}\u{E0062}(?:\u{E0065}\u{E006E}\u{E0067}|\u{E0077}\u{E006C}\u{E0073}|\u{E0073}\u{E0063}\u{E0074})\u{E007F}|\u200D\u2620\uFE0F)|\u{1F469}\u200D\u{1F469}\u200D(?:\u{1F466}\u200D\u{1F466}|\u{1F467}\u200D[\u{1F466}\u{1F467}])|\u{1F468}(?:\u200D(?:\u2764\uFE0F\u200D(?:\u{1F48B}\u200D)?\u{1F468}|[\u{1F468}\u{1F469}]\u200D(?:\u{1F466}\u200D\u{1F466}|\u{1F467}\u200D[\u{1F466}\u{1F467}])|\u{1F466}\u200D\u{1F466}|\u{1F467}\u200D[\u{1F466}\u{1F467}]|[\u{1F33E}\u{1F373}\u{1F393}\u{1F3A4}\u{1F3A8}\u{1F3EB}\u{1F3ED}\u{1F4BB}\u{1F4BC}\u{1F527}\u{1F52C}\u{1F680}\u{1F692}\u{1F9B0}-\u{1F9B3}])|[\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]\u200D[\u{1F33E}\u{1F373}\u{1F393}\u{1F3A4}\u{1F3A8}\u{1F3EB}\u{1F3ED}\u{1F4BB}\u{1F4BC}\u{1F527}\u{1F52C}\u{1F680}\u{1F692}\u{1F9B0}-\u{1F9B3}])|\u{1F469}\u200D(?:\u2764\uFE0F\u200D(?:\u{1F48B}\u200D[\u{1F468}\u{1F469}]|[\u{1F468}\u{1F469}])|[\u{1F33E}\u{1F373}\u{1F393}\u{1F3A4}\u{1F3A8}\u{1F3EB}\u{1F3ED}\u{1F4BB}\u{1F4BC}\u{1F527}\u{1F52C}\u{1F680}\u{1F692}\u{1F9B0}-\u{1F9B3}])|\u{1F469}\u200D\u{1F466}\u200D\u{1F466}|(?:\u{1F441}\uFE0F\u200D\u{1F5E8}|\u{1F469}[\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]\u200D[\u2695\u2696\u2708]|\u{1F468}(?:[\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]\u200D[\u2695\u2696\u2708]|\u200D[\u2695\u2696\u2708])|(?:[\u26F9\u{1F3CB}\u{1F3CC}\u{1F575}]\uFE0F|[\u{1F46F}\u{1F93C}\u{1F9DE}\u{1F9DF}])\u200D[\u2640\u2642]|[\u26F9\u{1F3CB}\u{1F3CC}\u{1F575}][\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]\u200D[\u2640\u2642]|[\u{1F3C3}\u{1F3C4}\u{1F3CA}\u{1F46E}\u{1F471}\u{1F473}\u{1F477}\u{1F481}\u{1F482}\u{1F486}\u{1F487}\u{1F645}-\u{1F647}\u{1F64B}\u{1F64D}\u{1F64E}\u{1F6A3}\u{1F6B4}-\u{1F6B6}\u{1F926}\u{1F937}-\u{1F939}\u{1F93D}\u{1F93E}\u{1F9B8}\u{1F9B9}\u{1F9D6}-\u{1F9DD}](?:[\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]\u200D[\u2640\u2642]|\u200D[\u2640\u2642])|\u{1F469}\u200D[\u2695\u2696\u2708])\uFE0F|\u{1F469}\u200D\u{1F467}\u200D[\u{1F466}\u{1F467}]|\u{1F469}\u200D\u{1F469}\u200D[\u{1F466}\u{1F467}]|\u{1F468}(?:\u200D(?:[\u{1F468}\u{1F469}]\u200D[\u{1F466}\u{1F467}]|[\u{1F466}\u{1F467}])|[\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}])|\u{1F3F3}\uFE0F\u200D\u{1F308}|\u{1F469}\u200D\u{1F467}|\u{1F469}[\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]\u200D[\u{1F33E}\u{1F373}\u{1F393}\u{1F3A4}\u{1F3A8}\u{1F3EB}\u{1F3ED}\u{1F4BB}\u{1F4BC}\u{1F527}\u{1F52C}\u{1F680}\u{1F692}\u{1F9B0}-\u{1F9B3}]|\u{1F469}\u200D\u{1F466}|\u{1F1F6}\u{1F1E6}|\u{1F1FD}\u{1F1F0}|\u{1F1F4}\u{1F1F2}|\u{1F469}[\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]|\u{1F1ED}[\u{1F1F0}\u{1F1F2}\u{1F1F3}\u{1F1F7}\u{1F1F9}\u{1F1FA}]|\u{1F1EC}[\u{1F1E6}\u{1F1E7}\u{1F1E9}-\u{1F1EE}\u{1F1F1}-\u{1F1F3}\u{1F1F5}-\u{1F1FA}\u{1F1FC}\u{1F1FE}]|\u{1F1EA}[\u{1F1E6}\u{1F1E8}\u{1F1EA}\u{1F1EC}\u{1F1ED}\u{1F1F7}-\u{1F1FA}]|\u{1F1E8}[\u{1F1E6}\u{1F1E8}\u{1F1E9}\u{1F1EB}-\u{1F1EE}\u{1F1F0}-\u{1F1F5}\u{1F1F7}\u{1F1FA}-\u{1F1FF}]|\u{1F1F2}[\u{1F1E6}\u{1F1E8}-\u{1F1ED}\u{1F1F0}-\u{1F1FF}]|\u{1F1F3}[\u{1F1E6}\u{1F1E8}\u{1F1EA}-\u{1F1EC}\u{1F1EE}\u{1F1F1}\u{1F1F4}\u{1F1F5}\u{1F1F7}\u{1F1FA}\u{1F1FF}]|\u{1F1FC}[\u{1F1EB}\u{1F1F8}]|\u{1F1FA}[\u{1F1E6}\u{1F1EC}\u{1F1F2}\u{1F1F3}\u{1F1F8}\u{1F1FE}\u{1F1FF}]|\u{1F1F0}[\u{1F1EA}\u{1F1EC}-\u{1F1EE}\u{1F1F2}\u{1F1F3}\u{1F1F5}\u{1F1F7}\u{1F1FC}\u{1F1FE}\u{1F1FF}]|\u{1F1EF}[\u{1F1EA}\u{1F1F2}\u{1F1F4}\u{1F1F5}]|\u{1F1F8}[\u{1F1E6}-\u{1F1EA}\u{1F1EC}-\u{1F1F4}\u{1F1F7}-\u{1F1F9}\u{1F1FB}\u{1F1FD}-\u{1F1FF}]|\u{1F1EE}[\u{1F1E8}-\u{1F1EA}\u{1F1F1}-\u{1F1F4}\u{1F1F6}-\u{1F1F9}]|\u{1F1FF}[\u{1F1E6}\u{1F1F2}\u{1F1FC}]|\u{1F1EB}[\u{1F1EE}-\u{1F1F0}\u{1F1F2}\u{1F1F4}\u{1F1F7}]|\u{1F1F5}[\u{1F1E6}\u{1F1EA}-\u{1F1ED}\u{1F1F0}-\u{1F1F3}\u{1F1F7}-\u{1F1F9}\u{1F1FC}\u{1F1FE}]|\u{1F1E9}[\u{1F1EA}\u{1F1EC}\u{1F1EF}\u{1F1F0}\u{1F1F2}\u{1F1F4}\u{1F1FF}]|\u{1F1F9}[\u{1F1E6}\u{1F1E8}\u{1F1E9}\u{1F1EB}-\u{1F1ED}\u{1F1EF}-\u{1F1F4}\u{1F1F7}\u{1F1F9}\u{1F1FB}\u{1F1FC}\u{1F1FF}]|\u{1F1E7}[\u{1F1E6}\u{1F1E7}\u{1F1E9}-\u{1F1EF}\u{1F1F1}-\u{1F1F4}\u{1F1F6}-\u{1F1F9}\u{1F1FB}\u{1F1FC}\u{1F1FE}\u{1F1FF}]|[#\*0-9]\uFE0F\u20E3|\u{1F1F1}[\u{1F1E6}-\u{1F1E8}\u{1F1EE}\u{1F1F0}\u{1F1F7}-\u{1F1FB}\u{1F1FE}]|\u{1F1E6}[\u{1F1E8}-\u{1F1EC}\u{1F1EE}\u{1F1F1}\u{1F1F2}\u{1F1F4}\u{1F1F6}-\u{1F1FA}\u{1F1FC}\u{1F1FD}\u{1F1FF}]|\u{1F1F7}[\u{1F1EA}\u{1F1F4}\u{1F1F8}\u{1F1FA}\u{1F1FC}]|\u{1F1FB}[\u{1F1E6}\u{1F1E8}\u{1F1EA}\u{1F1EC}\u{1F1EE}\u{1F1F3}\u{1F1FA}]|\u{1F1FE}[\u{1F1EA}\u{1F1F9}]|[\u{1F3C3}\u{1F3C4}\u{1F3CA}\u{1F46E}\u{1F471}\u{1F473}\u{1F477}\u{1F481}\u{1F482}\u{1F486}\u{1F487}\u{1F645}-\u{1F647}\u{1F64B}\u{1F64D}\u{1F64E}\u{1F6A3}\u{1F6B4}-\u{1F6B6}\u{1F926}\u{1F937}-\u{1F939}\u{1F93D}\u{1F93E}\u{1F9B8}\u{1F9B9}\u{1F9D6}-\u{1F9DD}][\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]|[\u26F9\u{1F3CB}\u{1F3CC}\u{1F575}][\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]|[\u261D\u270A-\u270D\u{1F385}\u{1F3C2}\u{1F3C7}\u{1F442}\u{1F443}\u{1F446}-\u{1F450}\u{1F466}\u{1F467}\u{1F470}\u{1F472}\u{1F474}-\u{1F476}\u{1F478}\u{1F47C}\u{1F483}\u{1F485}\u{1F4AA}\u{1F574}\u{1F57A}\u{1F590}\u{1F595}\u{1F596}\u{1F64C}\u{1F64F}\u{1F6C0}\u{1F6CC}\u{1F918}-\u{1F91C}\u{1F91E}\u{1F91F}\u{1F930}-\u{1F936}\u{1F9B5}\u{1F9B6}\u{1F9D1}-\u{1F9D5}][\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]|[\u231A\u231B\u23E9-\u23EC\u23F0\u23F3\u25FD\u25FE\u2614\u2615\u2648-\u2653\u267F\u2693\u26A1\u26AA\u26AB\u26BD\u26BE\u26C4\u26C5\u26CE\u26D4\u26EA\u26F2\u26F3\u26F5\u26FA\u26FD\u2705\u270A\u270B\u2728\u274C\u274E\u2753-\u2755\u2757\u2795-\u2797\u27B0\u27BF\u2B1B\u2B1C\u2B50\u2B55\u{1F004}\u{1F0CF}\u{1F18E}\u{1F191}-\u{1F19A}\u{1F1E6}-\u{1F1FF}\u{1F201}\u{1F21A}\u{1F22F}\u{1F232}-\u{1F236}\u{1F238}-\u{1F23A}\u{1F250}\u{1F251}\u{1F300}-\u{1F320}\u{1F32D}-\u{1F335}\u{1F337}-\u{1F37C}\u{1F37E}-\u{1F393}\u{1F3A0}-\u{1F3CA}\u{1F3CF}-\u{1F3D3}\u{1F3E0}-\u{1F3F0}\u{1F3F4}\u{1F3F8}-\u{1F43E}\u{1F440}\u{1F442}-\u{1F4FC}\u{1F4FF}-\u{1F53D}\u{1F54B}-\u{1F54E}\u{1F550}-\u{1F567}\u{1F57A}\u{1F595}\u{1F596}\u{1F5A4}\u{1F5FB}-\u{1F64F}\u{1F680}-\u{1F6C5}\u{1F6CC}\u{1F6D0}-\u{1F6D2}\u{1F6EB}\u{1F6EC}\u{1F6F4}-\u{1F6F9}\u{1F910}-\u{1F93A}\u{1F93C}-\u{1F93E}\u{1F940}-\u{1F945}\u{1F947}-\u{1F970}\u{1F973}-\u{1F976}\u{1F97A}\u{1F97C}-\u{1F9A2}\u{1F9B0}-\u{1F9B9}\u{1F9C0}-\u{1F9C2}\u{1F9D0}-\u{1F9FF}]|[#\*0-9\xA9\xAE\u203C\u2049\u2122\u2139\u2194-\u2199\u21A9\u21AA\u231A\u231B\u2328\u23CF\u23E9-\u23F3\u23F8-\u23FA\u24C2\u25AA\u25AB\u25B6\u25C0\u25FB-\u25FE\u2600-\u2604\u260E\u2611\u2614\u2615\u2618\u261D\u2620\u2622\u2623\u2626\u262A\u262E\u262F\u2638-\u263A\u2640\u2642\u2648-\u2653\u265F\u2660\u2663\u2665\u2666\u2668\u267B\u267E\u267F\u2692-\u2697\u2699\u269B\u269C\u26A0\u26A1\u26AA\u26AB\u26B0\u26B1\u26BD\u26BE\u26C4\u26C5\u26C8\u26CE\u26CF\u26D1\u26D3\u26D4\u26E9\u26EA\u26F0-\u26F5\u26F7-\u26FA\u26FD\u2702\u2705\u2708-\u270D\u270F\u2712\u2714\u2716\u271D\u2721\u2728\u2733\u2734\u2744\u2747\u274C\u274E\u2753-\u2755\u2757\u2763\u2764\u2795-\u2797\u27A1\u27B0\u27BF\u2934\u2935\u2B05-\u2B07\u2B1B\u2B1C\u2B50\u2B55\u3030\u303D\u3297\u3299\u{1F004}\u{1F0CF}\u{1F170}\u{1F171}\u{1F17E}\u{1F17F}\u{1F18E}\u{1F191}-\u{1F19A}\u{1F1E6}-\u{1F1FF}\u{1F201}\u{1F202}\u{1F21A}\u{1F22F}\u{1F232}-\u{1F23A}\u{1F250}\u{1F251}\u{1F300}-\u{1F321}\u{1F324}-\u{1F393}\u{1F396}\u{1F397}\u{1F399}-\u{1F39B}\u{1F39E}-\u{1F3F0}\u{1F3F3}-\u{1F3F5}\u{1F3F7}-\u{1F4FD}\u{1F4FF}-\u{1F53D}\u{1F549}-\u{1F54E}\u{1F550}-\u{1F567}\u{1F56F}\u{1F570}\u{1F573}-\u{1F57A}\u{1F587}\u{1F58A}-\u{1F58D}\u{1F590}\u{1F595}\u{1F596}\u{1F5A4}\u{1F5A5}\u{1F5A8}\u{1F5B1}\u{1F5B2}\u{1F5BC}\u{1F5C2}-\u{1F5C4}\u{1F5D1}-\u{1F5D3}\u{1F5DC}-\u{1F5DE}\u{1F5E1}\u{1F5E3}\u{1F5E8}\u{1F5EF}\u{1F5F3}\u{1F5FA}-\u{1F64F}\u{1F680}-\u{1F6C5}\u{1F6CB}-\u{1F6D2}\u{1F6E0}-\u{1F6E5}\u{1F6E9}\u{1F6EB}\u{1F6EC}\u{1F6F0}\u{1F6F3}-\u{1F6F9}\u{1F910}-\u{1F93A}\u{1F93C}-\u{1F93E}\u{1F940}-\u{1F945}\u{1F947}-\u{1F970}\u{1F973}-\u{1F976}\u{1F97A}\u{1F97C}-\u{1F9A2}\u{1F9B0}-\u{1F9B9}\u{1F9C0}-\u{1F9C2}\u{1F9D0}-\u{1F9FF}]\uFE0F|[\u261D\u26F9\u270A-\u270D\u{1F385}\u{1F3C2}-\u{1F3C4}\u{1F3C7}\u{1F3CA}-\u{1F3CC}\u{1F442}\u{1F443}\u{1F446}-\u{1F450}\u{1F466}-\u{1F469}\u{1F46E}\u{1F470}-\u{1F478}\u{1F47C}\u{1F481}-\u{1F483}\u{1F485}-\u{1F487}\u{1F4AA}\u{1F574}\u{1F575}\u{1F57A}\u{1F590}\u{1F595}\u{1F596}\u{1F645}-\u{1F647}\u{1F64B}-\u{1F64F}\u{1F6A3}\u{1F6B4}-\u{1F6B6}\u{1F6C0}\u{1F6CC}\u{1F918}-\u{1F91C}\u{1F91E}\u{1F91F}\u{1F926}\u{1F930}-\u{1F939}\u{1F93D}\u{1F93E}\u{1F9B5}\u{1F9B6}\u{1F9B8}\u{1F9B9}\u{1F9D1}-\u{1F9DD}]/gu, '')
```

2 then copy the result from the console, paste it. you'll find the 
[the bold dot is `/u200d`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27Wgg.png)

Comment: `str.replace(/\u200d/g, '')` ?  Not sure exactly what you want here.  By the way, your single line of code is not at all readable, and you might want to fix your formatting.  Perhaps `\u200d` is not covered by your current regex, yet you expected it to have been covered.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen   I'm less familiar to regex. ::cry::

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may add `\u{200D}` as an alternative, i.e. `/(?:<YOUR_EMOJI_REGEX>|\u{200D})+/gu`:

```js
var t ="help me ‍✈️‍‍‍‍".replace(
        /(?:\u{1F3F4}(?:\u{E0067}\u{E0062}(?:\u{E0065}\u{E006E}\u{E0067}|\u{E0077}\u{E006C}\u{E0073}|\u{E0073}\u{E0063}\u{E0074})\u{E007F}|\u200D\u2620\uFE0F)|\u{1F469}\u200D\u{1F469}\u200D(?:\u{1F466}\u200D\u{1F466}|\u{1F467}\u200D[\u{1F466}\u{1F467}])|\u{1F468}(?:\u200D(?:\u2764\uFE0F\u200D(?:\u{1F48B}\u200D)?\u{1F468}|[\u{1F468}\u{1F469}]\u200D(?:\u{1F466}\u200D\u{1F466}|\u{1F467}\u200D[\u{1F466}\u{1F467}])|\u{1F466}\u200D\u{1F466}|\u{1F467}\u200D[\u{1F466}\u{1F467}]|[\u{1F33E}\u{1F373}\u{1F393}\u{1F3A4}\u{1F3A8}\u{1F3EB}\u{1F3ED}\u{1F4BB}\u{1F4BC}\u{1F527}\u{1F52C}\u{1F680}\u{1F692}\u{1F9B0}-\u{1F9B3}])|[\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]\u200D[\u{1F33E}\u{1F373}\u{1F393}\u{1F3A4}\u{1F3A8}\u{1F3EB}\u{1F3ED}\u{1F4BB}\u{1F4BC}\u{1F527}\u{1F52C}\u{1F680}\u{1F692}\u{1F9B0}-\u{1F9B3}])|\u{1F469}\u200D(?:\u2764\uFE0F\u200D(?:\u{1F48B}\u200D[\u{1F468}\u{1F469}]|[\u{1F468}\u{1F469}])|[\u{1F33E}\u{1F373}\u{1F393}\u{1F3A4}\u{1F3A8}\u{1F3EB}\u{1F3ED}\u{1F4BB}\u{1F4BC}\u{1F527}\u{1F52C}\u{1F680}\u{1F692}\u{1F9B0}-\u{1F9B3}])|\u{1F469}\u200D\u{1F466}\u200D\u{1F466}|(?:\u{1F441}\uFE0F\u200D\u{1F5E8}|\u{1F469}[\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]\u200D[\u2695\u2696\u2708]|\u{1F468}(?:[\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]\u200D[\u2695\u2696\u2708]|\u200D[\u2695\u2696\u2708])|(?:[\u26F9\u{1F3CB}\u{1F3CC}\u{1F575}]\uFE0F|[\u{1F46F}\u{1F93C}\u{1F9DE}\u{1F9DF}])\u200D[\u2640\u2642]|[\u26F9\u{1F3CB}\u{1F3CC}\u{1F575}][\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]\u200D[\u2640\u2642]|[\u{1F3C3}\u{1F3C4}\u{1F3CA}\u{1F46E}\u{1F471}\u{1F473}\u{1F477}\u{1F481}\u{1F482}\u{1F486}\u{1F487}\u{1F645}-\u{1F647}\u{1F64B}\u{1F64D}\u{1F64E}\u{1F6A3}\u{1F6B4}-\u{1F6B6}\u{1F926}\u{1F937}-\u{1F939}\u{1F93D}\u{1F93E}\u{1F9B8}\u{1F9B9}\u{1F9D6}-\u{1F9DD}](?:[\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]\u200D[\u2640\u2642]|\u200D[\u2640\u2642])|\u{1F469}\u200D[\u2695\u2696\u2708])\uFE0F|\u{1F469}\u200D\u{1F467}\u200D[\u{1F466}\u{1F467}]|\u{1F469}\u200D\u{1F469}\u200D[\u{1F466}\u{1F467}]|\u{1F468}(?:\u200D(?:[\u{1F468}\u{1F469}]\u200D[\u{1F466}\u{1F467}]|[\u{1F466}\u{1F467}])|[\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}])|\u{1F3F3}\uFE0F\u200D\u{1F308}|\u{1F469}\u200D\u{1F467}|\u{1F469}[\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]\u200D[\u{1F33E}\u{1F373}\u{1F393}\u{1F3A4}\u{1F3A8}\u{1F3EB}\u{1F3ED}\u{1F4BB}\u{1F4BC}\u{1F527}\u{1F52C}\u{1F680}\u{1F692}\u{1F9B0}-\u{1F9B3}]|\u{1F469}\u200D\u{1F466}|\u{1F1F6}\u{1F1E6}|\u{1F1FD}\u{1F1F0}|\u{1F1F4}\u{1F1F2}|\u{1F469}[\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]|\u{1F1ED}[\u{1F1F0}\u{1F1F2}\u{1F1F3}\u{1F1F7}\u{1F1F9}\u{1F1FA}]|\u{1F1EC}[\u{1F1E6}\u{1F1E7}\u{1F1E9}-\u{1F1EE}\u{1F1F1}-\u{1F1F3}\u{1F1F5}-\u{1F1FA}\u{1F1FC}\u{1F1FE}]|\u{1F1EA}[\u{1F1E6}\u{1F1E8}\u{1F1EA}\u{1F1EC}\u{1F1ED}\u{1F1F7}-\u{1F1FA}]|\u{1F1E8}[\u{1F1E6}\u{1F1E8}\u{1F1E9}\u{1F1EB}-\u{1F1EE}\u{1F1F0}-\u{1F1F5}\u{1F1F7}\u{1F1FA}-\u{1F1FF}]|\u{1F1F2}[\u{1F1E6}\u{1F1E8}-\u{1F1ED}\u{1F1F0}-\u{1F1FF}]|\u{1F1F3}[\u{1F1E6}\u{1F1E8}\u{1F1EA}-\u{1F1EC}\u{1F1EE}\u{1F1F1}\u{1F1F4}\u{1F1F5}\u{1F1F7}\u{1F1FA}\u{1F1FF}]|\u{1F1FC}[\u{1F1EB}\u{1F1F8}]|\u{1F1FA}[\u{1F1E6}\u{1F1EC}\u{1F1F2}\u{1F1F3}\u{1F1F8}\u{1F1FE}\u{1F1FF}]|\u{1F1F0}[\u{1F1EA}\u{1F1EC}-\u{1F1EE}\u{1F1F2}\u{1F1F3}\u{1F1F5}\u{1F1F7}\u{1F1FC}\u{1F1FE}\u{1F1FF}]|\u{1F1EF}[\u{1F1EA}\u{1F1F2}\u{1F1F4}\u{1F1F5}]|\u{1F1F8}[\u{1F1E6}-\u{1F1EA}\u{1F1EC}-\u{1F1F4}\u{1F1F7}-\u{1F1F9}\u{1F1FB}\u{1F1FD}-\u{1F1FF}]|\u{1F1EE}[\u{1F1E8}-\u{1F1EA}\u{1F1F1}-\u{1F1F4}\u{1F1F6}-\u{1F1F9}]|\u{1F1FF}[\u{1F1E6}\u{1F1F2}\u{1F1FC}]|\u{1F1EB}[\u{1F1EE}-\u{1F1F0}\u{1F1F2}\u{1F1F4}\u{1F1F7}]|\u{1F1F5}[\u{1F1E6}\u{1F1EA}-\u{1F1ED}\u{1F1F0}-\u{1F1F3}\u{1F1F7}-\u{1F1F9}\u{1F1FC}\u{1F1FE}]|\u{1F1E9}[\u{1F1EA}\u{1F1EC}\u{1F1EF}\u{1F1F0}\u{1F1F2}\u{1F1F4}\u{1F1FF}]|\u{1F1F9}[\u{1F1E6}\u{1F1E8}\u{1F1E9}\u{1F1EB}-\u{1F1ED}\u{1F1EF}-\u{1F1F4}\u{1F1F7}\u{1F1F9}\u{1F1FB}\u{1F1FC}\u{1F1FF}]|\u{1F1E7}[\u{1F1E6}\u{1F1E7}\u{1F1E9}-\u{1F1EF}\u{1F1F1}-\u{1F1F4}\u{1F1F6}-\u{1F1F9}\u{1F1FB}\u{1F1FC}\u{1F1FE}\u{1F1FF}]|[#\*0-9]\uFE0F\u20E3|\u{1F1F1}[\u{1F1E6}-\u{1F1E8}\u{1F1EE}\u{1F1F0}\u{1F1F7}-\u{1F1FB}\u{1F1FE}]|\u{1F1E6}[\u{1F1E8}-\u{1F1EC}\u{1F1EE}\u{1F1F1}\u{1F1F2}\u{1F1F4}\u{1F1F6}-\u{1F1FA}\u{1F1FC}\u{1F1FD}\u{1F1FF}]|\u{1F1F7}[\u{1F1EA}\u{1F1F4}\u{1F1F8}\u{1F1FA}\u{1F1FC}]|\u{1F1FB}[\u{1F1E6}\u{1F1E8}\u{1F1EA}\u{1F1EC}\u{1F1EE}\u{1F1F3}\u{1F1FA}]|\u{1F1FE}[\u{1F1EA}\u{1F1F9}]|[\u{1F3C3}\u{1F3C4}\u{1F3CA}\u{1F46E}\u{1F471}\u{1F473}\u{1F477}\u{1F481}\u{1F482}\u{1F486}\u{1F487}\u{1F645}-\u{1F647}\u{1F64B}\u{1F64D}\u{1F64E}\u{1F6A3}\u{1F6B4}-\u{1F6B6}\u{1F926}\u{1F937}-\u{1F939}\u{1F93D}\u{1F93E}\u{1F9B8}\u{1F9B9}\u{1F9D6}-\u{1F9DD}][\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]|[\u26F9\u{1F3CB}\u{1F3CC}\u{1F575}][\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]|[\u261D\u270A-\u270D\u{1F385}\u{1F3C2}\u{1F3C7}\u{1F442}\u{1F443}\u{1F446}-\u{1F450}\u{1F466}\u{1F467}\u{1F470}\u{1F472}\u{1F474}-\u{1F476}\u{1F478}\u{1F47C}\u{1F483}\u{1F485}\u{1F4AA}\u{1F574}\u{1F57A}\u{1F590}\u{1F595}\u{1F596}\u{1F64C}\u{1F64F}\u{1F6C0}\u{1F6CC}\u{1F918}-\u{1F91C}\u{1F91E}\u{1F91F}\u{1F930}-\u{1F936}\u{1F9B5}\u{1F9B6}\u{1F9D1}-\u{1F9D5}][\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]|[\u231A\u231B\u23E9-\u23EC\u23F0\u23F3\u25FD\u25FE\u2614\u2615\u2648-\u2653\u267F\u2693\u26A1\u26AA\u26AB\u26BD\u26BE\u26C4\u26C5\u26CE\u26D4\u26EA\u26F2\u26F3\u26F5\u26FA\u26FD\u2705\u270A\u270B\u2728\u274C\u274E\u2753-\u2755\u2757\u2795-\u2797\u27B0\u27BF\u2B1B\u2B1C\u2B50\u2B55\u{1F004}\u{1F0CF}\u{1F18E}\u{1F191}-\u{1F19A}\u{1F1E6}-\u{1F1FF}\u{1F201}\u{1F21A}\u{1F22F}\u{1F232}-\u{1F236}\u{1F238}-\u{1F23A}\u{1F250}\u{1F251}\u{1F300}-\u{1F320}\u{1F32D}-\u{1F335}\u{1F337}-\u{1F37C}\u{1F37E}-\u{1F393}\u{1F3A0}-\u{1F3CA}\u{1F3CF}-\u{1F3D3}\u{1F3E0}-\u{1F3F0}\u{1F3F4}\u{1F3F8}-\u{1F43E}\u{1F440}\u{1F442}-\u{1F4FC}\u{1F4FF}-\u{1F53D}\u{1F54B}-\u{1F54E}\u{1F550}-\u{1F567}\u{1F57A}\u{1F595}\u{1F596}\u{1F5A4}\u{1F5FB}-\u{1F64F}\u{1F680}-\u{1F6C5}\u{1F6CC}\u{1F6D0}-\u{1F6D2}\u{1F6EB}\u{1F6EC}\u{1F6F4}-\u{1F6F9}\u{1F910}-\u{1F93A}\u{1F93C}-\u{1F93E}\u{1F940}-\u{1F945}\u{1F947}-\u{1F970}\u{1F973}-\u{1F976}\u{1F97A}\u{1F97C}-\u{1F9A2}\u{1F9B0}-\u{1F9B9}\u{1F9C0}-\u{1F9C2}\u{1F9D0}-\u{1F9FF}]|[#\*0-9\xA9\xAE\u203C\u2049\u2122\u2139\u2194-\u2199\u21A9\u21AA\u231A\u231B\u2328\u23CF\u23E9-\u23F3\u23F8-\u23FA\u24C2\u25AA\u25AB\u25B6\u25C0\u25FB-\u25FE\u2600-\u2604\u260E\u2611\u2614\u2615\u2618\u261D\u2620\u2622\u2623\u2626\u262A\u262E\u262F\u2638-\u263A\u2640\u2642\u2648-\u2653\u265F\u2660\u2663\u2665\u2666\u2668\u267B\u267E\u267F\u2692-\u2697\u2699\u269B\u269C\u26A0\u26A1\u26AA\u26AB\u26B0\u26B1\u26BD\u26BE\u26C4\u26C5\u26C8\u26CE\u26CF\u26D1\u26D3\u26D4\u26E9\u26EA\u26F0-\u26F5\u26F7-\u26FA\u26FD\u2702\u2705\u2708-\u270D\u270F\u2712\u2714\u2716\u271D\u2721\u2728\u2733\u2734\u2744\u2747\u274C\u274E\u2753-\u2755\u2757\u2763\u2764\u2795-\u2797\u27A1\u27B0\u27BF\u2934\u2935\u2B05-\u2B07\u2B1B\u2B1C\u2B50\u2B55\u3030\u303D\u3297\u3299\u{1F004}\u{1F0CF}\u{1F170}\u{1F171}\u{1F17E}\u{1F17F}\u{1F18E}\u{1F191}-\u{1F19A}\u{1F1E6}-\u{1F1FF}\u{1F201}\u{1F202}\u{1F21A}\u{1F22F}\u{1F232}-\u{1F23A}\u{1F250}\u{1F251}\u{1F300}-\u{1F321}\u{1F324}-\u{1F393}\u{1F396}\u{1F397}\u{1F399}-\u{1F39B}\u{1F39E}-\u{1F3F0}\u{1F3F3}-\u{1F3F5}\u{1F3F7}-\u{1F4FD}\u{1F4FF}-\u{1F53D}\u{1F549}-\u{1F54E}\u{1F550}-\u{1F567}\u{1F56F}\u{1F570}\u{1F573}-\u{1F57A}\u{1F587}\u{1F58A}-\u{1F58D}\u{1F590}\u{1F595}\u{1F596}\u{1F5A4}\u{1F5A5}\u{1F5A8}\u{1F5B1}\u{1F5B2}\u{1F5BC}\u{1F5C2}-\u{1F5C4}\u{1F5D1}-\u{1F5D3}\u{1F5DC}-\u{1F5DE}\u{1F5E1}\u{1F5E3}\u{1F5E8}\u{1F5EF}\u{1F5F3}\u{1F5FA}-\u{1F64F}\u{1F680}-\u{1F6C5}\u{1F6CB}-\u{1F6D2}\u{1F6E0}-\u{1F6E5}\u{1F6E9}\u{1F6EB}\u{1F6EC}\u{1F6F0}\u{1F6F3}-\u{1F6F9}\u{1F910}-\u{1F93A}\u{1F93C}-\u{1F93E}\u{1F940}-\u{1F945}\u{1F947}-\u{1F970}\u{1F973}-\u{1F976}\u{1F97A}\u{1F97C}-\u{1F9A2}\u{1F9B0}-\u{1F9B9}\u{1F9C0}-\u{1F9C2}\u{1F9D0}-\u{1F9FF}]\uFE0F|[\u261D\u26F9\u270A-\u270D\u{1F385}\u{1F3C2}-\u{1F3C4}\u{1F3C7}\u{1F3CA}-\u{1F3CC}\u{1F442}\u{1F443}\u{1F446}-\u{1F450}\u{1F466}-\u{1F469}\u{1F46E}\u{1F470}-\u{1F478}\u{1F47C}\u{1F481}-\u{1F483}\u{1F485}-\u{1F487}\u{1F4AA}\u{1F574}\u{1F575}\u{1F57A}\u{1F590}\u{1F595}\u{1F596}\u{1F645}-\u{1F647}\u{1F64B}-\u{1F64F}\u{1F6A3}\u{1F6B4}-\u{1F6B6}\u{1F6C0}\u{1F6CC}\u{1F918}-\u{1F91C}\u{1F91E}\u{1F91F}\u{1F926}\u{1F930}-\u{1F939}\u{1F93D}\u{1F93E}\u{1F9B5}\u{1F9B6}\u{1F9B8}\u{1F9B9}\u{1F9D1}-\u{1F9DD}]|\u{200D})+/gu, 
        ''
);
console.log("Result:", t);
console.log("Last char hex code:", t.charCodeAt(t.length-1).toString(16));
```

Comment: you're my god! ::cry::